# Display a single object with a DataGridView.DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, key-value

I'm used to display multiple objects with a DataGridView control in the following format

```
ID     Name     Address      [...]
ID1    Name1    123 street   [...]
ID2    Name2    456 street   [...]
```

This is simple to do with objects, properties and a `BindingList<>`.

I'd like my data to be "rotated" 90 degrees so that the grid displays a key:value pair such as

```
FieldName     Value
ID            ID1
Name          Name1
Address       123 street
```

Is this possible to achieve by binding some kind of list/dictionnary/other to the DataSource? I'm checking this approach because the object properties get/set makes it MUCH easier to handle data changes than handling a gazillion events exported from the DataGridView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a Windows Forms application? Have you considered using a PropertyGrid? It seems to me to be the natural choice for your problem unless you're doing an ASP.Net app.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you would want to just use [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.aspx) or [DetailsView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx)?  (Main difference is DetailsView gives you auto generated tables, with FormView you define a template)

If those aren't the answer, can you explain why you need to stick with DataGridView in particular?